# How to duplicate pointer to type int into uint8_t array inside structure array?

Tags: c

I am writing a program which will read the file and save values in arrays. 
this is my file:

```
communication1 : b8:27:eb:cf:54:2c, b8:27:eb:75:85:e4, 2000000;
communication2 : mm:27:eb:cf:54:2c, xx:27:eb:75:85:e4, 2200000;
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct mac{
        uint8_t address_bytes [6];
};

void main(){
    int count = 2, i = 0;
    char *Trash[4], *Time[4];
    int k=0;
    int mac1[6], mac2[6];
    char tempbuff[100];
    char trash[20], mac_s[20], mac_d[20], time[20];
    struct mac Mac1[2], Mac2[2];
    int j = 0;

    FILE *fptr =  fopen("config", "r");
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(!feof(fptr)){
       if (fgets(tempbuff,100,fptr)) {
               printf("\n%s", tempbuff);
               sscanf(tempbuff, "%15s : %17[^;], %17[^;], %17[^;];", trash, mac_s, mac_d, time);
                Trash[i] = strdup(trash);
                Time[i] = strdup(time);
                sscanf(mac_s, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &mac1[0], &mac1[1], &mac1[2], &mac1[3], &mac1[4], &mac1[5]);
                sscanf(mac_d, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &mac2[0], &mac2[1], &mac2[2], &mac2[3], &mac2[4], &mac2[5]);
                for(j = 0; j < 6; j++){
                        Mac1[i].address_bytes[j] = (uint8_t) mac1[j];
                        Mac2[i].address_bytes[j] = (uint8_t) mac2[j];
                }
                printf ("Mac1[%d] is %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x and Time is %s\n", i, Mac1[i].address_bytes[0], Mac1[i].address_bytes[1], Mac1[i].address_bytes[2], Mac1[i].address_bytes[3],
                                 Mac1[i].address_bytes[4],  Mac1[i].address_bytes[5], Time[i]);
                printf ("Mac2[%d] is %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x \n", i, Mac2[i].address_bytes[0], Mac2[i].address_bytes[1], Mac2[i].address_bytes[2], Mac2[i].address_bytes[3],
                                 Mac2[i].address_bytes[4],  Mac2[i].address_bytes[5]);
       }
       i++;
    }

    printf(" \n  time0 is %s time1 is %s \n", Time[0], Time[1]);


    fclose(fptr);

}
```

As you see, I am `sscanf` file and take 4 variables, than separately I `sscanf` mac addresses as pointers to type int and than trying to write them to a structure array. I have to achieve `uint8_t` values.

Output of this code is:

```
communication1 : b8:27:eb:cf:54:2c, b8:27:eb:75:85:e4, 2000000;
Mac1[0] is b8:27:eb:cf:54:2c and Time is 2000000
Mac2[0] is b8:27:eb:75:85:e4 

communication2 : mm:27:eb:cf:54:2c, xx:27:eb:75:85:e4, 2200000;
Mac1[1] is b8:27:eb:cf:54:2c and Time is 2200000
Mac2[1] is b8:27:eb:75:85:e4 

  time0 is 2000000 time1 is 2200000
```

The problem is, that I can't find the way to duplicate pointers into `uint8_t` field of structure array. With strings I already got the hint - `strdup`, what about `uint8_t`?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Your code seems to be properly reading in the values and printing them back out.  What exactly do you want to do that you aren't currently doing?

Comment: @dbush please, pay attention in output. When I am trying to scan mac addresses from the line  `communication2` in my `Mac1[**1**]` i have the same value as in `Mac1[**0**]` in `communication1` raw. I am expecting via this code, that I will have in  `Mac1[**1**]`  value like `mm:27:eb:cf:54:2c`

Comment: That wasn't clear from your explanation.  `mm` isn't a valid hexadecimal string, nor is `xx`, so no nothing gets read into `mac1` and `mac2` and their prior values are unchanged.

Comment: @dbush you are right! the dumbest question in stackoverflow, i guess. Thank you.

Comment: regarding: `void main(){`  There are two valid signatures for function: `main()`  `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Note that both signatures have a return type if `int`, not `void`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same things

Comment: when working with 'mac' address, URLS, IP addresses, etc it is (almost) always best to treat them as a `char` string

Comment: regarding: `sscanf(mac_s, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &mac1[0], &mac1[1], &mac1[2], &mac1[3], &mac1[4], &mac1[5]);`  1)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In this case, any returned value other than 6 indicates an error occurred  2) these statements cause the compiler to output: *untitled.c:28:33: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy plain bytes like `uint8_t`, use `memcpy`:

```
int main() {
    uint8_t s[6] = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6 };
    uint8_t *t;

    t = malloc(6*sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(t,s,6*sizeof(uint8_t));
    printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x\n", t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3],t[4],t[5]);
}
```

Comment: I guess there is a difference in your code and mine - I don't have 2 uint8_t arrays, i have just one array and pointers of type int.  so if i will do smth like 
`memcpy(Mac1[i].address_bytes[j], (uint8_t) mac1[j], 6*sizeof(uint8_t));`
I will have segmentation fault

Comment: @Max: you asked about a duplication of pointers and refered to strdup() yourself, and Stephan showed you memcpy(). You know what strdup() does, do you?

Comment: @kesselhaus From my point of view strdup() is trying to allocate memory to hold the string, which was given like a pointer to that string,  isn't it?

Comment: `strdup` requires a `\0`-terminated string (instead of any "length"-parameter), whereas `memcpy` is for copying arbitrary memory chunks (but requires to specify the length in bytes). `memcpy` does not allocate memory; adapted the answer to show how it works if you have to allocate memory, too.